# JMeter - How to use response assertion as condition of my If controller

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I have this structure:

[image]

In my Response Assertion I defined as JMeter variable this **Col2**

I can get the result of my query inside the listener or inside the body of my email defined in the SMTP Sampler, this way

```
${Col2_1}
```

but I cannot use its value as condition of my IF CONTROLLER

I tried this way with no luck:

```
${__jexl3(${Col2_1} > 10)}
```

I think I need to define a JRS233 Assertion or a Beanshell but I dont know how to pass it from response assertion to this JRS233 or Beanshell.

How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have 2 options:

1. (not recommended) untick `Interpret Condition as Variable Expression`
2. (recommended) switch to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) and amend your If Controller's condition to look like:

   ```
   ${__groovy((vars.get('Col2_1') as int) > 10 ,)}
   ```

`vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class, remaining code should be self-explanatory, if it isn't - check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide.

Comment: why is 1. not recommended?

Comment: Cause [If Controller says so](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/resources/messages.properties#L451). http://jmeter.apache.org/images/screenshots/if_controller_javascript.png. See [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) guide for more detailed explanation if needed